# Is VMware 8 compatible with Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: vmware, compatibility

I am using VMware 8.0.4 and want to install Ubuntu 12.04, but I have not been able to do so successfully. Can you suggest compatible versions of VMware and Ubuntu? In particular, will Ubuntu 12.04 work with VMware 8?

Answer (score 4):

VMware 8.0.4 is compatible with Ubuntu 12.04, you just need to apply a simple patch to allow the modules to build on the 3.2 kernel used by Ubuntu.

The patch is described and available on [this page](http://weltall.heliohost.org/wordpress/2012/01/26/vmware-workstation-8-0-2-player-4-0-2-fix-for-linux-kernel-3-2-and-3-3/), but the version in there needs to be changed to 8.0.4 to apply successfully.

**Here's how:**

To *download and* apply the patch,

- Open a terminal and type:

  ```
  mkdir vmw_patch && cd vmw_patch
  wget -O- http://weltall.heliohost.org/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/vmware802fixlinux320.tar.gz | tar -xz
  sed -i -e 's/8.0.2/8.0.4/g' patch-modules_3.2.0.sh 
  ./patch-modules_3.2.0.sh
  ```
- That should compile the modules without any errors.

> *Explanation:* `wget` downloads the patch, and `tar` extracts it without actually saving the downloaded file. `sed` updates 8.0.2 to 8.0.4 in the patching script so that it will run.

Comment: Actually on my pc Win7 is running . i want to first install VMware(8.0.4) and then within VMware i want to install Ubuntu(12.04). is it possible? are they compatible?

Comment: Yes, they are; I use such an exact configuration to answer AU questions when I'm on Windows.

Comment: @izx - I tried to apply your patch but it says: "VMWare is not installed (properly) on this PC." :/

Comment: @Shiki: the patch is for VMware Player/Wkstn on Linux host, NOT for VMware tools on an Ubuntu guest...