# Unable To Install VMware WorkStation 8 on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, ubuntu-one, vmware

Installing VMware 8.0.2 32bit

Ubuntu 12.04LTS 32bit BETA

My Kernel version is: 3.2.0-20-generic

```
vendettaowner@vendettaowner-desktop:~$ sudo sh VMware-Workstation-Full-8.0.2-591240.i386.bundle
```

Installs ok

When I launch I am asked to install modules which are compiled and loaded into the running kernel.

A window opens

> VMware Kernel Module Updater
>
> This fails on Virtual Network Device

**[ERROR LOG][1].**

**UPDATE:**

[PATCH][2].

When I try to add patch, following error:

```
vendettaowner@vendettaowner-desktop:~$ sudo ./patch-modules_3.2.0.sh
./patch-modules_3.2.0.sh: line 42: patch: command not found
```

What I Can Do To Lunch The Patch

I Tried But Without Any Useful

please help me

Answer (score 1):

Follow below commands one by one after opening a terminal

```
sudo apt-get install patch
mkdir vmw_patch && cd vmw_patch
wget -O- http://weltall.heliohost.org/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/vmware802fixlinux320.tar.gz | tar -xz    
./patch-modules_3.2.0.sh
```

Related Question:

[Is VMware 8 compatible with Ubuntu 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/q/159903/35775)

Comment: Thx But The Same Error Appear
   `root@vendettaowner-desktop:/home/vendettaowner# ./patch-modules_3.2.0.sh
./patch-modules_3.2.0.sh: line 42: patch: command not found`

Comment: See the updated answer

Comment: I Think There Is a prob with line 42 in can u check it please

Comment: Please install it `sudo apt-get install patch`

Comment: Thx Very Much Its work

Comment: Accept the answer by clicking on tick at upper left of the answer

Answer (score 0):

The patch didn't fix the problem for me.

What did work was installing Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit (I had been using 32 bit for legacy reasons...).

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. if you have a question please ask that by clicking Ask Question button(top right corner)