# VMware player 4.04 installing on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, vmware

I downloaded vmware player 4.04 and run into the problem of virtual network device fail.

After googling a bit, I found [How do I install VMware Player?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130937/how-do-i-install-vmware-player-4-0-3) and applied as this answer suggest, which is the following:

1) I downloaded the tarball http://weltall.heliohost.org/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/vmware802fixlinux320.tar.gz

2) Change the plreqver=4.04

3) and run it. Everything looks working until I try to run vmware player again.

Now, it failed at the step "Virtual Machine Monitor" which was OK before I applied the patch. I guess the patch skerewed the whole VMware kernel modules.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a terminal, navigate to directory where the patch is downloaded & unzipped.

Execute following

`sed -i -e 's/8.0.2/8.0.4/g' patch-modules_3.2.0.sh`. Re run the patch.

If you get a `patch: command not found` error, please install patch using

`sudo apt-get install patch` and rerun the patch script.

let us know how it went.

Related Question:

[Unable To Install VMware WorkStation 8 on ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/171512/35775)

[Is VMware 8 compatible with Ubuntu 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/q/159903/35775)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems working but after some moment, it dies with the following messages

Comment: make[2]: *** [/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only/netif.o] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only] Error 2
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-23-generic-pae'
    make: *** [vmnet.ko] Error 2
    make: Leaving directory `/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only'
    Unable to install vmnet

Comment: The lines above looks very messy, How can I align them with lines in comments?

Comment: you need to edit the question. I would suggest to remove the vmplayer completely and start a fresh install and patch

Comment: The patch should be used after using `sed` from my answer and changing `plreqver` version. I just installed it two days age. :)

Comment: Oh! after removing and reinstalling it works!! Thanks a lot :)